# How to check availability of an ID in same page?

Tags: php, javascript

To be specific, I want to make code like Yahoo's Registration (Yahoo ID - Check Availability) checking the availability. The problem here is I need to use PHP to connect, get, and search/verify if the entered value in the textbox is unique.

I tried passing a JavaScript value to a PHP variable, but based on my research, doing this isn't possible, so I need another possible solution to get the value of the textbox and set it to a PHP variable.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use ajax call instead. See the link : http://youhack.me/2010/05/04/username-availability-check-in-registration-form-using-jqueryphp/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to get data from JavaScript to PHP (in a typical environment) is to deliver it over HTTP. Doing this without leaving the page is known as [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), and usually done using [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/).

There are no shortage of [tutorials](http://jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html) describing how to do this, nor any shortage of [libraries](http://microjs.com/#ajax) that will help (plus, of course, all the large libraries such as [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax for manipulating this situation.. Have a look at following link.
http://www.digimantra.com/technology/javascript/check-username-availability-validation-ajaxphp/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX for that.

AJAX is used to send and receive data from the server. So, on the server side, you can create a URL that checks whether a username (can be passed using get/post) is available or not & accordingly send a response. At the client side, depending on the response you receive from the server, you can alert the user.